# routing with tollroad + motorway give bad request

Tags: here-api

Hie,
I use the following request with mode parameter

&mode = 'fastest;car;tollroad:-2'       ==>   Ok
&mode = 'fastest;car;mototorway:-2'     ==>   Ok

&mode = 'fastest;car;tollroad:-2;mototorway:-2' ==> Bad request

I didnt found my error? parameters exclusive? coding error? restriction?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The mode features are comma-separated:

```
&mode = 'fastest;car;tollroad:-2,mototorway:-2'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Is it working ? If it is, you may accept the answer